# Боты некорректно поднимают и бросают оружие

Tags: c#, unity3d

Занимаюсь созданием игры, дошел до момента, когда нужно запрограммировать ботов на поднятие оружия и бросания его в следующих случаях: боезапас пуст/встретил более ценное оружие (за это отвечает инициализированная переменная value). Создал врага, поместил в префаб для более удобного клонирования. И проблема: если враг один на карте, то все работает идеально, он поднимает оружие, с которым сталкивается, стреляет из него или бьет, а затем бросает, если боезапас пуст или столкнулся с более ценным оружием. Но если враг не один, то они начинают делать не то, что ожидалось. Другими словами, враги теперь, столкнувшись с оружием, заставляют его исчезнуть (так и задумано, это процесс поднятия), но после этого оно не появляется у них в инвентаре или появляется у другого врага. Не пойму связь между врагами, нужна помощь в этом. Ниже код главного скрипта, отвечающего за поднятие и выбрасывание оружия.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class EnemyDrop : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Текущее количество патронов.
    public int currentAmmo;
    //Отклонение от места, куда падает оружие при его выбрасывании
    private Vector3 offset;
    //Активные в инвентаре оружия.
    //LABEL0
    public GameObject _activeMelee;
    public static GameObject activeMelee;
    public GameObject _activeBottle;
    public static GameObject activeBottle;
    public GameObject _activeGun;
    public static GameObject activeGun;
    public GameObject _activePistol;
    public static GameObject activePistol;
    [HideInInspector] 
    //ID оружия, которое в последний раз было в руках.
    public int activeId;
    //ID оружия, которое герой готов подобрать.
    private int activeQuestion;
    //Объект, который в руках до обмена.
    private GameObject currentChange;
    //Объект, с которым меняемся.
    private GameObject groundWeapon;
    //Положение игрока в пространстве.
    public Transform enemy;
    [HideInInspector] 
    //Есть ли оружие в руках?
    private bool ifThereIsSmthInHand;
    [HideInInspector] 
    //Приступаем к подниманию оружия только в случае, если оно касается игрока. Переменная хранит в себе логическое значение этого условия.
    public bool mightDoNextTurn;
    [HideInInspector] 
    //Имя активного оружия.
    private string nameOfActive;
    //Имя оружия, с которым столкнулись.
    private string nameOfWeapon;
    //Массив оружий.
    public GameObject[] arrayOfObjects;
    //Массив IDов оружий.
    public int[] arrayOfIds;
    //Массив, хранящий боезапас каждого оружия.
    public int[] arrayOfAmmo;
    [HideInInspector] 
    //В полете ли оружие?
    public bool isFlying;
    [HideInInspector] 
    public float speed;
    //Время в полете.
    private float timeWhileFlying;
    [HideInInspector] 
    public float timing;
    public int[] arrayOfValues;
    private bool pickedAnEmptyWeapon;
    public string nameactive;
    public string nameWeapon;
    public int question;

    //Метод получения имени активного оружия.
    public static string getActiveWeapon () //LABEL1
    { 
        if (activeGun.activeSelf) { 
            return "Gun"; 
        } 
        if (activeMelee.activeSelf) { 
            return "Melee"; 
        } 
        if (activeBottle.activeSelf) {
            return "Bottle";
        }
        if (activePistol.activeSelf) {
            return "Pistol";
        }
        return "empty"; 
    }
    //Метод получения логической переменной, отвечающей за наличие или отсутствие оружия в руках.
    public static bool ifThereIsSomethingInHand ()//LABEL2
    { 
        if (activeMelee.activeSelf || activeGun.activeSelf || activeBottle.activeSelf || activePistol.activeSelf)
            return true;
        else
            return false; 
    }
    //Метод Start, в котором происходит инициализация начальных данных.
    void Start ()
    { //LABEL3
        activeMelee = _activeMelee; 
        activeGun = _activeGun; 
        activeBottle = _activeBottle;
        activePistol = _activePistol;
        activeBottle.SetActive (false);
        activeMelee.SetActive (false); 
        activeGun.SetActive (false);
        activePistol.SetActive (false);
        offset = new Vector3 (0f, 0.9f, -0.5f); 
        mightDoNextTurn = false; 
        speed = 2;
        timeWhileFlying = 2; 
        activeId = 26; 
    }
    //Метод Update, в котором совершается ряд действий:
    //сперва проверяется наличие оруждия в руках, затем получается его имя.
    //Далее, в зависимости от наличия или отсутсвия оружия, противник должен бросить, сменить или поднять оружие.
    void Update ()
    { 
        ifThereIsSmthInHand = ifThereIsSomethingInHand (); 
        nameOfActive = getActiveWeapon (); 
        if (ifThereIsSmthInHand) { 
            if (mightDoNextTurn)
                ChangeWeapon ();
            else
                actionDrop (); 
        } else if (mightDoNextTurn)
            actionPick (); 
        nameactive = nameOfActive;
        nameWeapon = nameOfWeapon;
        question = activeQuestion;
    }
    //Метод выбрасывания оружия: по опустошении магазина активное оружие отключается, а на землю путем метода DropPos()
    //выбрасывается оружие с ID оружия, которое в последний раз было в руках.
    private void actionDrop () //LABEL4
    { 
        if (currentAmmo == 0 && nameOfActive == "Gun") { 
            activeGun.SetActive (false); 
            arrayOfObjects [activeId].SetActive (true); 
            arrayOfValues [activeId] = 0;
            DropPos (); 
            activeId = 26; 
        } 
        if (currentAmmo == 0 && nameOfActive == "Pistol") { 
            activePistol.SetActive (false); 
            arrayOfObjects [activeId].SetActive (true); 
            arrayOfValues [activeId] = 0;
            DropPos (); 
            activeId = 26; 
        } 
    }

    public void deathDrop ()
    {
        arrayOfObjects [activeId].SetActive (true);
        DropPos (); 
    }
    //Метод поднятия оружия: при касании с оружием метод проверяет и включает в руках поднятое оружие,
    //отключая то, ID которого соответствует ID оружия, которое касается противника.
    private void actionPick ()//LABEL5
    {
        switch (nameOfWeapon) { 
            case "FireWeapon":
                activeGun.SetActive (true);
                break; 
            case "MeleeWeapon": 
                activeMelee.SetActive (true); 
                break; 
            case "BottleWeapon":
                activeBottle.SetActive (true);
                break;
            case "PistolWeapon":
                activePistol.SetActive (true);
                break;
            default: 
                break; 
        } 
        arrayOfObjects [activeQuestion].SetActive (false); 
        activeId = activeQuestion; 
        mightDoNextTurn = false;  
    }
    //Метод перемещения оружия под игрока и разрешение его полета.
    private void DropPos ()
    { 
        arrayOfObjects [activeId].transform.position = enemy.transform.position - offset; 
        arrayOfObjects [activeId].transform.rotation = enemy.transform.rotation; 
    }
    //Метод для смены оружий. В обменную переменную кладется текущее активное оружие,
    //далее последовательно происходят действия методов actionDrop() и actionPick(). Обмен происходит при условии большего значения пользы лежащего оружия.
    private void ChangeWeapon ()//LABEL6
    { 
        if (arrayOfValues [activeQuestion] > arrayOfValues [activeId]) { 
            if (activeMelee.activeSelf)
                currentChange = activeMelee; 
            if (activeGun.activeSelf)
                currentChange = activeGun; 
            if (activeBottle.activeSelf)
                currentChange = activeBottle;
            if (activePistol.activeSelf)
                currentChange = activePistol;
            currentChange.SetActive (false); 
            arrayOfObjects [activeId].SetActive (true); 
            DropPos ();
            activeId = 26; 
            arrayOfObjects [activeQuestion].SetActive (false); 
            activeId = activeQuestion; 
            mightDoNextTurn = false; 
            if (nameOfWeapon == "BottleWeapon") {
                activeBottle.SetActive (true);
            }
            if (nameOfWeapon == "MeleeWeapon") {
                activeMelee.SetActive (true); 
            }
            if (nameOfWeapon == "FireWeapon") {
                activeGun.SetActive (true);
            }
            if (nameOfWeapon == "PistolWeapon") {
                activePistol.SetActive (true);
            }
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)//LABEL7
    { 
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Weapon") { 
            groundWeapon = other.gameObject; 
            activeQuestion = other.gameObject.GetComponent<IdOfWeapon> ().localId; 
            if (arrayOfValues [activeQuestion] == 0)
                activeQuestion = 26;
            //Разбираемся, с чем мы столкнулись 
            if (activeQuestion >= 0 && activeQuestion <= 1000 && activeQuestion != 26) {
                if (activeQuestion < 31) { 
                    nameOfWeapon = "MeleeWeapon"; 
                } 
                if (activeQuestion < 61 && activeQuestion >= 31) { 
                    nameOfWeapon = "BottleWeapon"; 
                } 
                if (activeQuestion >= 61 && activeQuestion < 91) {
                    nameOfWeapon = "FireWeapon"; 
                }
                if (activeQuestion >= 121 && activeQuestion < 151) {
                    nameOfWeapon = "PistolWeapon";
                }
            }  
            mightDoNextTurn = true; 
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerStay (Collider other)//LABEL8
    { 
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Weapon") { 
            groundWeapon = other.gameObject;
            activeQuestion = other.gameObject.GetComponent<IdOfWeapon> ().localId; 
            if (arrayOfValues [activeQuestion] == 0)
                activeQuestion = 26;
            //Разбираемся, с чем мы столкнулись 
            if (activeQuestion >= 0 && activeQuestion <= 1000 && activeQuestion != 26) {
                if (activeQuestion < 31) { 
                    nameOfWeapon = "MeleeWeapon"; 
                } 
                if (activeQuestion < 61 && activeQuestion >= 31) { 
                    nameOfWeapon = "BottleWeapon"; 
                } 
                if (activeQuestion >= 61 && activeQuestion < 91) {
                    nameOfWeapon = "FireWeapon"; 
                }
                if (activeQuestion >= 121 && activeQuestion < 151) {
                    nameOfWeapon = "PistolWeapon";
                }
            }
            mightDoNextTurn = true; 
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit (Collider other)
    { 
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Weapon") { 
            mightDoNextTurn = false; 
            nameOfWeapon = ""; 
        } 
        activeQuestion = 26; 
    }
}
```

Comment: выкладывай проект полностью. трудно что -то сказать. но похоже что у тебя поднятие оружия общее или допустим отдаётся последнему/предыдущему боту. Разбираться без отладчика не буду. Попробуй в отладчике проследить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну хоть изучайте основы языков программирования, в частности c#, у вас static поля activegun  и т.д существуют в единственном экземпляре и не принадлежат экземплярам своего класса. Следовательно, в Start вы инициализуете их каждым обьектом, в итоге получаете ссылки на обьекты последнего созданного врага, поэтому с одним врагом все прекрасно работает, а с двумя и более все получает последний созданный.

Comment: Спасибо, это решило все

Comment: @ЭмильБураиндов помечайте вопрос как решенный.